# How to get WAMP to work on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wamp

I am having trouble getting WAMP to work on Windows 8. Are there any tips to try?

Comment: any specific ways its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give this a try, [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). It gives you a stack of the following apps:

- Apache
- MysqlPHP
- XDebug
- PhpMyadmin
- SQLBuddy
- webGrind

It also provides you with addons for installing additional functionality within the above software.